# angular 2 fullcalendar,refetchEvents not working(full calendar is not a function error)

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular2-directives, ui-calendar, fullcalendar-2

I am using angular 2 fullcalendar for one of my projects.everything works fine as long as i have the data ready before rendering the calender.If an event is triggered and data comes from backend,i am facing problem while using refetch function.I wil explain the code first and describe the error.
I have installed

```
npm install fullcalendar

npm i angular2-fullcalendar

npm install jquery

npm install moment
```

in app.module.ts

i have imported

```
import {CalendarComponent} from "angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar";
```

and i have declared in the declaration:[]

in html i am displaying calendar using

```
<div class="ui red segment" *ngIf="dataAvailable">
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calOptions" id="mycal" #mycal>
</angular2-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

In the component i have

```
import {CalendarComponent} from 'angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar';
import {Options} from 'fullcalendar';

declare var $:any;
import * as moment from "moment";
```

and i have a refference to the tag like

```
 @ViewChild('mycal', { read: ElementRef }) myCal: ElementRef;
```

and my calendar configuration looks like

```js
 calOptions: any = {
        height:350,
        defaultDate: moment(new Date(),'YYYY-MM-DD'),
        editable: false,
        stick:true,
        
        events:this.events,
        selectable:false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        header: {
                  left: 'month basicWeek basicDay',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'today prev,next'
                },
        displayEventTime: false,
        addEventSource:this.events,
        defaultView:'basicWeek',
       
        dayRender: (date, cell)=> {
                        var today = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    //    today = moment(today).toDate();
                        
                        for(let item of this.holidayList){
                        
                        if(item.holidayDate === moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))
                        {
                         cell.css("background-color", "#e4564a");
                         
                        }
                        }
          } 
  };
```

**Problem**

Now when the new data comes if i try

```
$(this.myCal.nativeElement).fullCalendar('addEventSource', events)
```

It gives an error saying

> Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

and if i try using

$('#mycal').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources',this.events);

it gives the error

> caused by: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function

also if i use

```
$('angular2-fullcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources',this.events);
```

same error comes.What am i doing wrong??Please help.I am really stuck;

**update**

i did i did

```
@ViewChildren('mycal') cal: QueryList<CalendarComponent>
```

and after the new data comes,in the subscribe method i did,

```
this.cal.forEach(div => 
  {
    div.fullCalendar('removeEventSource', this.events);
     div.fullCalendar('addEventSource', this.events);
      div.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

  }
```

Now it when the new data comes,old data is not removed from the view,but it is getting appended with the existing view.

Comment: when are you calling `$(this.myCal.nativeElement)` ?

Comment: i tried calling it after the data comes back from the server,and when isDataAvailable becomes true.Dint work.I tried calling it in ngAfterViewInit as wel,it dint work either

Comment: you should try with `@ViewChildren()` `QueryList` class has a `changes` Observable that will notify when new elements arrive.

Comment: may be a small example with respect to my code would help better as i am new to QueryList

Comment: okay its kind of working now ,but the problem now is that ,it displaying the calendar with duplicate events.ie on first refresh it shows one event,on data change it shows two ,etc..any workaround ?

Comment: adding the handler only once and not on every change ?

Comment: I updated my question with what i did,where should add the handler method to make sure its executed only once

Comment: Sorry ,was using the fullcalendar function wrongly,now its working fine..Please post an answer ,:..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using an `*ngIf`, your element might be present or not.

Instead of using `@ViewChild('mycal')` You should consider using `@ViewChildren('myCal')` and subscribe to `QueryList.changes` `Observable`:

```js
@ViewChildren('myCal')
cal: QueryList < ElementRef > ;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.cal.changes
    .startWith(this.cal)
    .filter(list => list.length > 0)
    .subscribe(list => {
      console.log(list.first);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are making it too complicated:

```
 @ViewChild('mycal') calendar : CalendarComponent;
```

then whenever you want to refresh you simply call:

```
this.calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

I don't know why to call ViewChildren to get an array of calendars when it seems you only have 1 in your html.